# Create multiple folders named after the Items of a ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Clicking on the the `Get List` Button:

1. I fill a ListBox with the file names contained ina a selected.
2. I then separate the files extensions and fille another ListBox, removing the *dot*.

Clicking on the `Create Folders` Button,

I want to remove the duplicate extensions and create folders named after the items in the ListBox.
i.e., create folders with names: `doc`, `docx`, `dwg` etc.

```
private void btn_list_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox_ex.Items.Clear();
    FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (FBD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        lbl_path.Text = FBD.SelectedPath;
        listBox_name.Items.Clear();
        string[] filename = Directory.GetFiles(FBD.SelectedPath);

        foreach (string file in filename)
        {
            listBox_name.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
            listBox_ex.Items.Add(Path.GetExtension(file).Replace(".", ""));                  
        }
    }
}

private void btn_CreateFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog FBD2 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (FBD2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        lbl_pathCreated.Text = FBD2.SelectedPath;
    }

    string path = lbl_pathCreated.Text;
    if (!Directory.Exists(path)) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("already exit");
    }
}
```

[image: ListBox filled with File names and file extensions]

Comment: _"second half not completed"_ - by that do you mean the code to create the subfolders for each document type?

Comment: yes i want a create folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative method, using 2 **`List<string>`** objects to store the current files' selection and the files extensions as [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct), [Ordered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) elements.

The Lists are then used as the [ListBox.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource).
A `ListBox.Items` collecton is reset when the DataSource is changed.

When a destination Path is selected, each item in the List of extensions is used to create a Directory in the selected path.
No need to check whether the Directory already exists: [Directory.CreateDirectory()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory) just ignores it.

You might want to add a validation procedure for the Path a user seleted. The user may have picked a *weird* destination.

```
List<string> fileNames = null;
List<string> fileExtensions = null;

private void btn_list_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lbl_path.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).ToList();
            fileExtensions = fileNames.Select(item => 
                Path.GetExtension(item).Replace(".", "")).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
            listBox_name..DataSource = fileNames.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList();
            listBox_ex.DataSource = fileExtensions;
        }
    }
}

private void btn_CreateFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            lbl_pathCreated.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            fileExtensions.ForEach(item => 
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(fbd.SelectedPath, item)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much your solution. how to remove full path in file names of filename listbox and i want a listbox1 files move to each folder to matching extension

Comment: The same way you extract the file extension: with the Path's class `Path.GetFileName()` method. I'll make an edit. How to organize and move files to the new folders is another question, so you need to post another one for this matter (it's a different topic, we can post a soluton that answers the question at hand).

Comment: The `fileNames` List is filtered when filling the corresponding ListBox, so only the files Names are shown in the control. But the List contains the full path of the files. You can use this list to move the files it enumerates. See the LINQ's [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) method for this. You can use it to group the files by their extension.

Comment: i was created it. thanks your help. but have a problem. i click create folder button , come folder browse dialog box. i was canceled it, coming Exception,

Comment: You need to specify what exception you receive. If you apply the code as written here, no exception is raised when the dialog is canceled. If you have code outside the `if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)` condition, then an exception is likely to raise when a user cancels the dialog.